# What Runs before the Magento Profiler Starts?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have found that the `TTFB` is really high, like 1 - 1.2 seconds.

But the profiler says 200ms.

What is causing this huge descrpency.

I am using a local php server:

`php -S magento:4444 router.php`

Answer (score 0):

The first `Varien_Profiler::start();` is in `app/Mage.php` in the `run()` Method at the begin. This Method is called in your index.php at the very end.
So, everything in your index.php runs before the Profiler starts.

I assume that your machine is slow. Magento/PHP needs a lot of resources and reads a lot of file from your disk. If you have not much memory and not a SSD, it could be a explanation. To optimize you server/localhost would be another topic and I think your initial question is answered :)

**//edit**
I revoke my opinion in terms of the server performance.
What I forgot to mention is, that the `app/Mage.php` have Code before the class `Mage` is initialize. Magento do the whole autoloading stuff. Take a look in Mage.php Line 1 - 60. So, Magento collect all Files and include them.

Comment: Yeah but if the machine is slow that would reflect in the profiler timing right?

Comment: yeah, seams legit. I edited my answer.